# Out of Memeory when Rounding corner of Image

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, out-of-memory

I have a `FrameLayout` in which there are three images in which first(left side) and second(right side) image are rounded from ONE CORNER, I am creating this by using `BitmapDrawable` and then rounding image by this method.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int topLeftX, int topLeftY, int topRightX, int topRightY, int bottomRightX, int bottomRightY, int bottomLeftX, int bottomLeftY) {
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        // the float array passed to this function defines the x/y values of the corners
        // it starts top-left and works clockwise
        // so top-left-x, top-left-y, top-right-x etc
        RoundRectShape rrs = new RoundRectShape(new float[]{topLeftX, topLeftY, topRightX, topRightY, bottomRightX, bottomRightY, bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY}, null, null);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        rrs.resize(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        rrs.draw(canvas, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
```

**problem: 
its working well but my app having more images so sometimes when app using frequently its crash and generates this error.**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 406992 byte allocation with 397304 free bytes and 387KB until OOM
                                                                              at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:857)
                                                                              at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:834)
                                                                              at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:801)
```

**i had also tried to use RoundedBitmapDrawable Class , but its only works for rounding all corners . If there is any other method or way to solve my problem ,please let me know .**

Comment: reduce size `new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight())`

Comment: i have already use this line in method

Answer (score 0):

Add largeHeap in AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    ...
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your Bitmap completed its work then make it recycle and null.

```
if(bitmap!=null)
{
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap=null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Jaspreet Kaur mention, your code did not free memory of old bitmap. However, this might a bit complicated. Suppose you're using certain framework load the image so basically those framework will use Lru cache to cache your image. If it was the case then there is a problem:

1. your original image will be remaining in LruCache of the library which will automatically recycle when more image being loaded.
2. your new rounded image did not store in LruCache of the library and that mean you need to manage your own LruCache and free the image later.

I doubt that you can access to LruCache of the library. I would recommend to try other way around such as if you're using Glide then try to implement custom transformation instead as it will taking care of memory management for you.

If you're not using any library to loaded the image, I believe you must using LruCache which is accessible then, just like @Jaspreet Kaur mention, free or recycle the old bitmap that passed in and keep the new image in LruCache then LruCache will taking care of free the image when it reach memory limit.

Hope this would help.